# Information on permissions group

Tags: sharepoint-server, permissions, groups

Is there a way to view who created a permissions group and when it was created - from the Site Admin level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SharePoint by default doesn’t display this information in the user interface. To check the data, you can enable audit settings for site settings and automatically save the report into a library. Note: to enable audit settings, you need to have site collection administrator's permissions.

Then if a user creates a group after that, the change will be logged into audit log. Site administrator could check the report to find the creator of a group.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. - DJ